# Prevent duplicate submission with post in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that submits with a button via jquery `post()`. Unfortunately it submits two times and as a result it duplicates records in mysql.

I have two files: `register.php` (that contains html and javascript) and `tttt.php` that runs sql.

My question is: how to modify my scripts in order to prevent double submission?

Please help me out.
[this is link of the page](http://sharetime.ir/public/register.php)

Part of `register.php`:

```
<form id="regForm" method="post" action="tttt.php">
<!-- (...) -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#sub").click(function(){

                     var data=$("#regForm :input").serializeArray();
        var posting = $.post($("#regForm").attr("action"), data, function(info){




             if(info==="yes"){$("#result1").html("ثبت نام انجام شد");}

        else{if(info==="no"){$("#result1").html("ثبت نام  با موفقیت انجام نشد");           }}

        });
        posting.done(function( data ) {

                  if(data==="no"){
                     $('#result1').fadeOut(8000, function() {
                     $(this).empty().show();
                     $("#regForm").submit(function(){
                     return false;});
                                                             });
                                   }  
    else       {
         $('#result1').fadeOut(12000, function() {
         $(this).empty().show();
        $("#regForm").submit(function(){
                       return false;});  
                                                 });
                       $("input:text ").val("");
                    $("input:password ").val("");

    }         


     });
            });

          $("#regForm").submit(function(){
                  return false;

                     });

              </script>
```

Part of `tttt.php`:

```
   <?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
require_once("../private/connection.php");





if(isset($_POST["name"])  && !empty($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && !empty($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["birthday"]) && !empty($_POST["birthday"])&&  isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && isset( $_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["confirmPassword"]) && !empty($_POST["confirmPassword"]) ){

        $name     =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
        $lastname =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
        $birthday =$conn->real_escape_string($conn->real_escape_string($_POST["birthday"]);
        $email    =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        $password =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   



        if ($result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO students (student_name,student_family,student_birthday,student_email,student_password)
VALUES ('$name','$lastname' ,'$birthday' ,'$email','$hashed_password')")) {


            echo "yes";
} 
        else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}




    }else


{  echo "no";}  

        $conn->close();     
    ?>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White is correct and you're also not properly checking if those post values exist. If they don't, calling `if ( $_POST[ "name" ] )` will throw an error. you need to check `isset( $_POST[ "name" ] )`. Also, use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php to do all your DB work. MUCH safer.

Comment: Try `.one()` so that the click event is only applied once...

Comment: your `if` has a `submit`, your `else` has a submit, and yet another `submit` after the conditional ends.

Comment: @Daniel  I updated the code is it possible tell me if it is vulnerable to sql injection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change button type as button

```js
<button type="button" id="sub" name="sub" class="btn btn-warning form-control pull-right">ثبت نام <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok
"></span></button>
```

Comment: better to bind to submit handler so user can still use keyboard to submit

Comment: thank you Ravi it solved my problem.

Comment: how could I add a preloader when it is being processed in server?for example display "Loading..." beside button.

Comment: Do you want after clicking on submit, like once you click on submit it shows something like Saving.... or what?

Comment: @Ravi yes exactly.wanna display a text when when data is being saved on database. but i don't know where should i  write the code.

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: @Ravi yes i use bootstrap.

Comment: you add attribute  data-loading-text="Saving..."(Any text) in button like 
<button  data-loading-text="Saving..." type="button" id="sub" name="sub" class="btn btn-warning form-control pull-right">ثبت نام <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok
"></span></button>
and on click of button
$("#sub").click(function(){
    //Before Submitting the form
   $("#sub").button("loading");
  //After getting the response(Success or failure)
   $("#sub").button("reset");
});

Comment: @Ravi after i changed type from "submit" to "button" the validation of form doesn't work anymore.i'm using http://formvalidation.io/.what should I do about it?

Comment: you put like below
if($("#formId").valid()==true){
      $("#formid").submit();
}

Comment: @Ravi is  there another way to prevent double submission instead of changing type from  "submit" to button?

Comment: don't do jquery submit

Comment: @Ravi your solution about preloader works like a charm.thank you

Comment: @Ravi do you know how could i add preloader for formvalidation.io when it being processed on server? my email field check for duplicate email bu i don't know how set preloader for that.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the record, just do a check in the database if the user does not already exist. By what I see your unique columns would be email and the password hash. And do some proper error handling.